# How to Move Bone Joints in Pose Mode like in Edit Mode? (without scaling)

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

I wonder how to move bones in pose mode like as you would grab the tips in edit mode and move them but without scaling the bone.

Tried to set this up with damped track or ik rig. At both the target to follow which would imitate the tip/joint of the bone can be moved anywhere. It has to stick to the bone though.

Any techniques?

Comment: use limit distance constraint

Comment: set clamp region to on surface

Comment: yup figured that out too

Comment: sadly this doesnt work with an ik target though.

Comment: that what i was waiting for , the bones start acting weird since they depend on each other